# Matches A but not B in Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex, match

I have a big document. Lets scale it to

```
location=State-City-House
location=City-House
```

So What I want to do is replace all those not starting with State, with some other string. Say "NY". But those starting with State must remain untouched.

So my end result would be

```
location=State-City-House
location=NY-City-House
```

1.Obviously I cant use String.replaceAll().

2.Using Pattern.matcher() is tricky since we are using two different patterns where one must be found and one must not be found.

3.Tried a dirty way of replacing "location=State" first with "bocation=State" then replacing the others and then re-replacing.

So, A neat and simple way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst`? See https://regex101.com/r/aK1nH1/2. Do you need to replace all matches with the same `NY-` value?

Comment: Hint: sometimes regular expressions are a good answers; sometimes they are not. Keep in mind the **cost** of maintaining complex regexes over time. Every java programmer understands `if (matches regexA) { ... do one thing } else  { ... do other thing }`. How many java programmer will immediately understand for example the solution provided by anubhava? (not saying that his solution is wrong; but: if you need a regex GURU to come up with that solutions; how high are your chances that **you** will be able to change/enhance that regex tomorrow; being offline, without access to SO regex GURUs)?

Comment: @Jägermeister: You do not have to be a guru to understand a lookaround. If someone asks for a regex solution, (s)he must understand the basics. Also, the `(?m)^(location=)(?!State)` is not a difficult pattern. anubhava just does not always explain what he suggests, that is the only drawback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use `replaceAll` with a negative lookahead:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll( "(?m)^(location=)(?!State)", "$1NY-" );
```

- `(?m)` sets `MULTILINE` modifier so that we match anchors `^` and `$` in each line
- `(location=)` matches `location=` and captures the value in group #1
- `(?!State)` is the negative lookahead to fail the match when `State` appears after the captured group #1 i.e. `location=`
- In replacement we use `$1NY-` to make it `location=NY-` at start.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI0yJ4/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly, you don't actually have the string "State" in your input, but varying strings that represent states. 
But some of your text lines are missing the state altogether and only have the name of the City and House. Is that correct? In that case, the defining characteristic between the 2 kinds of lines is the number of dashes.

`^location=([^-]+)-([^-]+)$`

The above regex matches only full lines with only 1 dash.

I might have misunderstood the task. It would be easier if you would post some of the actual input.